# How can I read a character from an InputStream and return it in a Supplier<Integer> (Java)

Tags: java, methods, inputstream, supplier

So I have a method I need to implement. It gets an InputStream and returns a Supplier like this:

`public Supplier<Integer> buildPipe(InputStream input)`

Now I want to read a character from the InputStream (probably with the read()-method) and return it, but I have no idea how to store it as an int so I can return it with the Supplier.

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: So basicly what you are asking is how to parse String to Integer?

Comment: While this can be done, it’s a bad idea.  You’ll have to wrap every single character read in a try/catch.  It’s not worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really possible to go directly from an `InputStream` to a `codepoint` without going through a decoding bridge. For that you need to know that `Charset`, or assume it. `InputStreamReader` is that bridge.

for example:

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[]{1,2});
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Now you can have your Supplier from a Reader rather than an input stream.

```
Supplier<Integer> next(InputStreamReader reader) {
    Supplier<Integer> s = () -> {
        try {
            return reader.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    };
    return s;
}
```

Please note that `InputStreamReader` is stateful and hence your `Supplier` wont be referential transparent as one would expect.

Answer (score -1):

InputStream is a byte-oriented stream, if you need a character, not a byte, you should use InputStreamReader. Maybe something like this will work for you:

```
  public Supplier<Integer> buildPipe(InputStream input) {
    return () -> {
      try {
        return Integer.valueOf(input.read());
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return Integer.valueOf(-1);
    };
  }
```

Comment: printing stack trace is poor exception handling. You should wrap the IOException in a RuntimeException and throw that